# Managing multiple instances of Resque and Redis

Tags: redis, resque, god

I am trying to have God monitor two instances of Resque, one for production and one for staging.

So I start two Redis instances on system boot: redis_6379 and redis_6380.

Then I'm using Daemontools to start and monitor God.

My God script looks something like this:

```
God.watch do |w|
  w.dir      = "#{rails_root}"
  w.name     = "resque-#{num}"
  w.group    = 'resque'
  w.interval = 30.seconds
  w.env      = {"QUEUE"=>"critical,high,low", "RAILS_ENV"=>rails_env}
  w.start    = "rake resque:work QUEUE='*' RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
  ....
end
```

Don't I need to somehow associate the staging and production resque processes with particular redis instances?

I'm gradually piecing this together but I think I'm missing a key piece.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need to specify `QUEUE` and `RAILS_ENV` in `w.start` since you already specified them in a proper place, `w.env`.

Second, this script runs a single instance of resque in a `rails_env` environment (whatever its value is).

I suggest something like this:

```
%w(staging production).each do |rails_env|
  God.watch do |w|
    w.dir      = "#{rails_root}" # <= is this path the same for production and staging?
                                 # if not, change accordingly.
    w.name     = "resque-#{rails_env}"
    w.group    = 'resque'
    w.interval = 30.seconds
    w.env      = {"QUEUE"=>"critical,high,low", "RAILS_ENV"=>rails_env}
    w.start    = "rake resque:work"
    ....
  end
end
```